# node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have created a small server for communication using node.js and socket io

Server:

```js
var express = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express')
var io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io');
var server = express.createServer();
server.listen(8888,'localhost');
io = io.listen(server);
io.of("namespace").on('connection', function(client){
     client.emit("message",'connection successful');
     client.on('message', function(m){
        console.log("received message"+m);
         client.broadcast(m);
     });
});
```

Client:

```hmtl
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Comet Test</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a id='customAlert' href="#" onclick='sendMessage("customAlert")'>publish customAlert</a></p>
    <p><a id='customAlert2' href="#" onclick='sendMessage("customAlert2")'>publish customAl
    <script type="text/javascript">
     // Start the socket
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888/namespace');
      socket.on('error', function (reason){
        console.error('Unable to connect Socket.IO', reason);
      });
      socket.on('message', function(msg){
          console.log(msg);
      });
      function sendMessage(m) {
        console.log("sending message"+m);   
        socket.emit("message",m);
      }
    </script>
</body>
```

Communication does not happen, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked if io.connect is trying to connect to port 8888 on the server?

Comment: is there a way to handle if io.connect fails to connect ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your server is listening on port 8888, you need the client to connect to the server on port 8888.

The following line in your client code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/namespace');
```

Should read:

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888/namespace');
```

Comment: the html file is accessed through apache, so should this create any issues.

Comment: I have edited my code to include the new changes, now i start my server and when i open the html in the browser the server gets a client connect request and authorisation is successful, but when I try to send some messages the messages are lost and not caught by the server

Comment: You could try adding event listeners both server and client-side for both connection and disconnection events. This might give you a clearer picture of whether the connection is still alive when sending messages.