# What is needed to networking communication between multiple users in a game?

Tags: networking, webserver

I've never done networking stuff before so I am kind of confused. Suppose for example, I have a simple pong game setup. If I wanted to make that multiplayer in a sense that two people with different phone can play against each other, then ignoring the code to set that up what else do I need. So I need a dedicated server that handles the communication between the multiple users correct? Can I somehow make my mac into a server that handles that communication? What are my other options? Are there free servers that I can use which I can utilize into my game. I just need to put the pieces together because although I have decent knowledge about the whole project in pieces, I am not sure how to combine everything and put everything together. Can someone clear the uncertainty for me? Thanks.

Comment: Just for future reference, you should try spacing out your paragraph so it's not a giant block of text to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these cases I use [Nodejs](http://nodejs.org/), [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) and [Expressjs](http://expressjs.com/), but usually free hosts do not have these software installed. But you can test locally from your Mac and your internal network.

Review post similars to:

- [Multiplayer HTML5, Node.js, Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244230/multiplayer-html5-node-js-socket-io)
- [node.js and socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849393/node-js-and-socket-io?rq=1)

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the help alditis. Would it be possible to use my local apache that I have set up on my mac to handle the server side code and have my client be able to constantly talk to it when needed? Can you give me some high level guidelines please?

Comment: Would it be something like, the client code would be hosted by my apache server. The html the apache server returns on a device would  internally connect to the server hosted on my mac via express.js and the client would now be able to update via server communication?